# как совместить выполнение telebot с основной программой в цикле на python

Tags: python, telebot

Есть основная программ(main), которая крутится в цикле и telebot, который отслеживает сообщения из телеграма. В данной реализации основная программа отрабатывает один раз и все, а дальше только telebot. Подскажите, как сделать параллельно работу основного блока и  telebot.

```
import telebot

bot_token = 'my token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, threaded=False)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    if message.text == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Связь есть')

def main():
    print('123')

while True:

    main()

    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Bot polling section error: " + str(e))
```

Comment: bot.infinity_poling()

Comment: После замены bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0) на bot.infinity_polling() все осталось точно так же.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решения своего вопроса. Телебот вынес в функцию и запускаю отдельным потоком.

```
import telebot
from threading import Thread

bot_token = 'мой токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, threaded=False)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    if message.text == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Связь есть')

def main():
    print('123')

def tele():
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Bot polling section error: " + str(e))


Thread(target=tele).start()

while True:

    main()
```